# Is it reasonable to say that each random variable has one and only one variance?

Tags: probability

In probability theory and statistics, variance is the expectation of the squared deviation of a random variable from its mean.

Is it reasonable to say that each random variable has one and only one variance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Variance is defined only when expectation is finite so there are random variables with no variance.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a term to refer to that kind of random variables?

Comment: No, there is no special term for these.